# Showing that $\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\int_{\{x:f_n(x)\ge t\}}|f_n|d\mu\right)=0.$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space, $f_n$ measurable and $|f_n|\le g$ a.e. for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ where $g$ is integrable. Prove that $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\int_{\{x:f_n(x)\ge t\}}|f_n|d\mu\right)=0.$$

This is what I have tried, but I can't solve the problem yet.

Let $\epsilon >0$. Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $\int|f_n|\le\int g$, so $f_n$ is integrable. Consider the finite measure $v(A)=\int_{A}|f_n|$ for each $A\in\Sigma.$

Call $A_m:=\{x:f_n(x)\ge m\}$ for $m\in\mathbb{N}$. The intersection of all $A_m$ is $\{x:f_n(x)=\infty\}$, and this set has measure zero because $f_n$ is integrable.

So one can find $m_n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\int_{\{x:f_n(x)\ge m_n\}}|f_n|d\mu<\epsilon$. But of course $m_n$ depends of $n$, and we need some $t$ that works for every $f_n,n\in\mathbb{N}$.

The condition $|f_n|\le g$ says to me that we need to apply the dominated convergence theorem but I don't know how.

Any hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|f_n|\le g$, we have that $\{x:f_n(x)\ge t\}\subseteq\{x:g(x)\ge t\}$, so
$$
\sup_n\int_{\{x:f_n(x)\ge t\}}|f_n|\,d\mu
\le \sup_n\int_{\{x:g(x)\ge t\}}|f_n|\,d\mu
\le\int_{\{x:g(x)\ge t\}}g\,d\mu
$$
Now, show that rightmost integral approaches zero as $t\to\infty$ using DCT.

Comment: Thank you! But why do we need to use DCT? I think that as $g$ is integrable, that integral aproacches zero as $t\to\infty$, because $\{x:g(x)=\infty\}$ has measure zero. Am I wrong?

Comment: You don't need DCT. Using DCT is one way to prove that $E_n\searrow E$ implies $\int_{E_n}g\,d\mu\searrow \int_E g\,d\mu$, provided $g$ is integrable. Another way to prove this is to use the fact that $\nu(E)=\int_E g\,d\mu$ is a measure, then use continuity from above.